# ld: framework not found com.apple.mobileicons

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently developing my first iOS app which i have tested on simulator till date. Yesterday my developer account was approved and with a mammoth amt of excitement, I tried to deploy my app on the device for testing.
My device iOS is 4.1 and I am currently using Xcode 4.2

While compiling, it generated 1 error and the message was:

```
ld: framework not found com.apple.mobileicons

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

In detail

```
Ld /Users/adstuckltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbee-hkxqvccjpaucdlfsdppurvxweneb/Build/Intermediates/fbee.build/Debug-iphoneos/fbee.build/Objects-normal/armv6/fbee normal armv6
cd "/Users/adstuckltd/Desktop/MacBook Updtes/02 June/fbee"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.1
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/adstuckltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbee-hkxqvccjpaucdlfsdppurvxweneb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/adstuckltd/Desktop/MacBook Updtes/02 June/fbee/AviaryInc-Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-iOS-fb6747f/AviarySDK" -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system "-L/Users/adstuckltd/Desktop/MacBook Updtes/02 June/fbee/AviaryInc-Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-iOS-b4367ba/AviarySDK" -F/Users/adstuckltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbee-hkxqvccjpaucdlfsdppurvxweneb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks "-F/Users/adstuckltd/Desktop/MacBook Updtes/02 June/fbee/Images/Image Ref/Heavy Metal HD.theme/Bundles" -filelist /Users/adstuckltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbee-hkxqvccjpaucdlfsdppurvxweneb/Build/Intermediates/fbee.build/Debug-iphoneos/fbee.build/Objects-normal/armv6/fbee.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -miphoneos-version-min=4.1 -lz.1.2.5 -lsqlite3.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework SenTestingKit -framework CFNetwork -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework StoreKit -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lAviarySDK -framework com.apple.mobileicons -o /Users/adstuckltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fbee-hkxqvccjpaucdlfsdppurvxweneb/Build/Intermediates/fbee.build/Debug-iphoneos/fbee.build/Objects-normal/armv6/fbee
```

What could be the problem ? Please help me out, I really want to see how my app works on an actual device.

Thanx

Comment: MobileIcons.framework is private. As a guess that framework doesn't exist forthe 4.1 SDK. Which simulator version are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.2 and iOS5.. but i am trying to test on iOS 4.1....

Comment: i am unable to find the answer of the following question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the listed frameworks linked in `Build Phase` `Link Binary with Libraries`

```
SenTesting
CFNetwork
Accelerate
Core Data etc.
```

I would also update to the newest `iOS 5.1.1` and `Xcode 4.3.2`

Comment: what could be the issue please help me out

Comment: resolved it.... actually there were some issues in plist as well as I had to revisit the included frameworks to check for the same.. and as suggested, i upgraded to latest xcode 4.5